# "Sonar Profile didn't match" error however the profile is mapped correctly in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

While building the code, the following message is logged in the SonarQube Scanner step:

`sonar.profile was set to 'xxxxxxxx profile' but didn't match any profile for any language. Please check your configuration.`

This message is logged even though the 'xxxxxxxx profile' is available and mapped to the corresponding language. This was working in the past and encountering this error only recently. There have been no recent changes in the configuration or related settings via UI and also no module of any other language (i.e. other language without association with quality profile) is committed.

What could be the cause of this issue and how to resolve this?

Comment: `sonar.profile` is deprecated.

Comment: Got to know that sonar.profile is deprecated. In that case it shouldn't even expect for that property. But why is this error being thrown ? Should we amend any other property else where?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Probably it is connected with the fact that it's trying to analyze a project which include only files written in some other language than your profile is defined for. For example in my case it's crashing on project which only have pom.xml file (parent pom) while the profile is defined for java.
It was working ok until we updated to version 6.5 of SonarQube.

Comment: Same problem with our projects. We know well that the parameter is deprecated but this should not cause an error like this.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam So if `sonar.profile` is deprecated, is there some alternative way to specify a sonar profile at build time? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`sonar.profile` was deprecated *several years ago* with the introduction of multi-language analysis.

If you nonetheless use `sonar.profile` - rather than having a project administrator associate the project to the desired profiles via the UI - then you *must have* a profile of that name *for each language* found during analysis. From the error, you don't.

Answer (score 2):

We ran into the same issue and at first thought the settings does not work. But it actually works.

You need to have one quality-profile with the matching name for every language used by the analyzed project. For instance:

- if you specify **sonar.profile=MY_PROFILE**
- and your project uses **Java** and **XML** as languages (as our project does)
- you need to have **two** quality-profiles with **MY_PROFILE** as name, one for Java one for XML